# Spring-Boot: additional layer of adressing config-items

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying the config-feature of Spring-Boot.

**application.properties**

```
mycfg.a = a1a
mycfg.b = b2b
```

**Config.java**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties (prefix = "mycfg")
@Validated
public class Config
{
    @NotNull
    private String a;
    private String b;
   
    public String getA ()
    {            return this.a;
    }

    public void setA (String s)
    {            this.a = s;
    }
 
    public String getB ()
    {            return this.a;
    }

    public void setB (String s)
    {            this.b = s;
    }
}
```

This is working well.

Now I want to add an additional layer in my config-file - lets say for item b.

**application.properties**

```
mycfg.a = a1a
mycfg.layer.b = b2b
```

Now my app raises an error at booting. It is because it does not know mycfg.layer.b.

How can I add this layer in Config.java?

Comment: You can probably use @Value annotation over a field to fetch that field's value via properties.

Like @Value("${mycfg.layer.b}") private String b;

Comment: Or you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059989/how-to-group-properties-with-spring-boot-configuration-properties for grouping via ConfigurationProperties